# Can't login into PhpMyAdmin EasyPHP after setting password

Tags: mysql, easyphp

I installed EasyPHP 5.3.6, opened PhpMyAdmin, created a new databased and set password for root user. "Naturally" following that I was unable to login into PhpMyAdmin anymore, getting the infamous 1045 Access Denied error.

I tried everything I could find - setting password (in two places) in config.inc.php doesn't seem to work. I also tried changing AllowNoPassword to true (or false, whichever one it was not originally), that didn't do anything. I tried going through phpmyadmin/scripts/signon.php and enter the password there (it's the correct password, I saved it in my password manager) and couldn't login either. I also tried following instructions for resetting MySQL password I found but they used a mysqld-nt.exe which I didn't find in my installation. I also tried uninstalling EasyPHP and reinstalling it (and before doing that I used ccleaner to remove any registry issues it found, though admittedly there was nothing there about mysql) and it of course retained the "incorrect password" and wouldn't let me login.

Short of reformatting my harddrive I'm not sure what else I can do. (How does it keep the broken settings after uninstall??)

Any help would be appreciated.

I also would like to understand why doing something supposedly good to protect your database turns out to be such a painful procedure that it is actually recommended to leave the root user without a password? *sigh*

Comment: When I had this I cleared the cache....I think...and it was fine. This was for PHPMyAdmin though.

Comment: Thank you! I feel stupid for not trying something so simple, guess sometimes it's hard to see the forest through the trees. :)

Comment: No worries, it often takes an outside eye to see that kind of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearing cache allowed me to get to phpmyadmin after re-installing easyphp. Thanks to Danae above.

Answer (score 3):

Go to EasyPHP-12.1\modules\ folder. Open folder for PhPMyAdmin version you are using (in my case it was phpmyadmin356x130206112511). Find file **config.inc.php**. Right click edit with Notepad.

Under line:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
```

paste this line:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'YOURPASSWORD';
```

where YOURPASSWORD is your desired password.

Save file and **refresh** the "Local Web" page.

Comment: Worked like a charm after clearing cache. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I just killed mysql and restarted, it worked fine for me.

Answer (score -2):

Happened to me also. Unfortunately my internet decided to go down at the same time and I was unable to google this page.  The "help" that comes up when you are denied access is really lame ( but hat's off to easyphp creator. )  The "help" tells you " check your configuration files"